# Convergence conditions for $\sum\limits_{n\ge1}(-1)^{n-1}\frac{(\log n)^p}n$ where $p\in\mathbb R$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, absolute-convergence

As far as I know, the fact that the series starts at $n=1$ is intentional, so I know I can immediately omit the case where $p\le0$.

I decided to use the alternating series test, so to show that the summand is decreasing in absolute value, I consider the function $f(x)=\dfrac{(\log x)^p}x$ and found that its derivative is positive for $x\in(1,e^p)$ and decreasing for $x>e^p$.

I also find that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(\log n)^p}n=0$$

via L'Hopital's rule.

But barring that doubt, it would seem the series converges for all $p>0$.

Yet when I check via Mathematica, I get

```
In[1]:= SumConvergence[(-1)^(n-1)Log[n]^p/n, n]

Out[1]= 1 + p < 0
```

I don't understand this result at all. When $p=0$ the series is clearly convergent and has a value of $\log2$. Larger values of $p$ also return summations in terms of the Euler-Mascheroni and Stieltjes constants. Perhaps this is a bug in the software?

So my question is,

> Is my answer correct, and if not, where do I go wrong?

Comment: I think it should be a bug. Just trying something like : SumConvergence[(-1)^(n - 1) (Log[n])^(10)/n, n] (just replaced $p$ with $10$) returns True (assuming it's not faulty there as well) as well as SumConvergence[(-1)^(n - 1) (Log[n])^(10^(10^5))/n, n] and SumConvergence[(-1)^(n - 1) (Log[n])^(-10^(10^5))/n, n]. L'Hopital does work (apply it $p$ many times) and you'll get $0$ for the limit. Showing that $a_{n+1}<a_{n}$ is a little more challenging. I'm not really sure what values of $p$ this doesn't converge (maybe all reals if you consider $n\neq1$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track. The limit

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(\log n)^p}n=0$$

should be one that's under your belt. How could the measly $\log n,$ no matter if raised to the zillionth power, compete with any power of $n?$ I'm not sure why you're having trouble with L'Hopital. Both top and bottom $\to \infty$ right? So apply monsieur L'Hopital. You get $p(\log n)^{p-1}/n.$ If $p\le 1,$ you're done, as the last expression $\to 0.$ If not, apply LHR again. Clearly after a finite number of phone calls to the good marquis, you'll get a limit of $0.$

Comment: I'm not so much having trouble using LHR to compute the limit, but rather convincing myself the limit exists so that I *can* use LHR. I've been reminded too many times about this condition that I feel the need to be as careful as possible :)

Comment: I don't understand this "limit exists" business. What is it you think LHR says?

Comment: D'oh, my mistake - I'm confusing the requirement that $\lim\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$ must exist, which is then equal to $\lim\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$. So much for trying to be careful :P

Answer (score 2):

There is a simple argument if you are willing to use the integral form of the logarithm. If $\alpha > 0$ then $$\log n = \int_1^n t^{-1} \, dt < \int_1^n t^{-1 + \alpha} \, dt = \frac{n^\alpha - 1}{\alpha} < \frac{n^\alpha}{\alpha}.$$ In particular if $p > 0$ you can take $\alpha = \frac 1{2p}$ to get $$(\log n)^p < (2p)^p n^{\frac 12} $$ and thus $$0 \le \frac{(\log n)^p}{n} < \frac{(2p)^p}{n^{\frac 12}} \to 0$$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: Great, this is easy to follow and takes care of my first question. Thanks!

Comment: Note that $\log(n) = \lim_{a \to 0} (n^a-1)/a$.